# Como adicionar campos dinamicamente em Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Eu gostaria de adicionar campos dinamicamente no DjangoAdmin.

Arquivo models.py:

```
class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Arquivo admin.py:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Como a interface gráfica está atualmente:

[image]

Eu gostaria de adicionar dinamicamente vários livros para um determinado autor.

Em vez de ter um checkbox com "N" opções, eu gostaria de ter "N" selectboxes, tantos quantos necessários.

Algo como isto:

[image]

Eu tentei usar [Inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin), mas eu só conseguia adicionar um livro novo, não selecionar os que já existem.

Qual é a forma mais elegante de fazer isto?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o [filter_horizontal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) do django irá resolver seu problema.

Na sua class do admin.py, coloque a tag para indicar isso.

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('author',)

admin.site.register(Book)
```

Você terá um select multiple igual o de permissão com a opção de adicionar um novo elemento.